# cannot upload files to django rest framework using react js

Tags: python, django, reactjs

I'm using react Js to upload an image to django restframework.
here I'm sending post request using fetch API.

Eapp.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Eapp extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      profilePic: null,
    };
    this.inpuElement = null;
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(e){
    this.setState({profilePic: e.target.files[0]});
  }
  handleSubmit(){
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('profile_pic',this.state.profilePic);
    fetch('http://10.42.0.1:8000/auth/profile-pic/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
      body:formData,
    }).then(res => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  render(){
      return(
        <div>
          <input
            type="file"
            multiple={false}
            ref={(input) => { this.inpuElement = input; }}
            accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>submit</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Eapp;
```

error msg

```
Eapp.jsx:19 POST http://10.42.0.1:8000/auth/profile-pic/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
handleSubmit @ Eapp.jsx:19
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:542
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:581
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:438
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:452
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:836
executeDispatchesInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:858
executeDispatchesAndRelease @ react-dom.development.js:956
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:967
forEachAccumulated @ react-dom.development.js:935
processEventQueue @ react-dom.development.js:1112
runEventQueueInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:3607
handleTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:3616
handleTopLevelImpl @ react-dom.development.js:3347
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:11082
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:2330
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:3421
example:1 Failed to load http://10.42.0.1:8000/auth/profile-pic/: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
Eapp.jsx:30 TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

django

```
 views.py
    class ProfilePictureView(generics.CreateAPIView):
        permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
        serializer_class = ProfilePictureSerializer
        parser_classes = (parsers.FormParser,parsers.MultiPartParser, parsers.FileUploadParser, )

        def perform_create(self, serializer):
            print(self.request.FILES['profile_pic'])
            serializer.save(user=User.objects.get(pk=2))


models.py

class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to='media')
    face_encodings = models.BinaryField(null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.first_name)


serializers.py

class ProfilePictureSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['profile_pic','user']
        read_only_fields = ('user',)

class ProfilePictureSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['profile_pic','user']
        read_only_fields = ('user',)

class ProfilePictureSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['profile_pic','user']
        read_only_fields = ('user',)


raise MultiPartParserError('Invalid boundary in multipart: %s' % boundary.decode())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

I have included django cors headers, every other api route is working except this one. I've tried different methods of post request but still got the errors.
It's not seems access to the server because every other route is working.
I've tried MultiPart parser fileUpload parser in django but still got error status 400, 500 .

Comment: Try using ready to go solution with filepond:
https://hvitis.dev/how-to-connect-filepond-reactjs-and-drf-extension

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try without content-type in header,it will help for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
"Content-Type":"multipart/form-data"
```

in the handleSubmit function!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! This question has already been answered, and an answer was accepted. If you believe your answer does add something more to said question, please elaborate why this solution is better then the one accepted. Otherwise it won't be likely to attract much appreciation.