# python requests multipart/form-data

Tags: python, python-requests

i want to send mulitpart/form-data to a server. it is working fine with postman . But when i use python requests it is giving 500 error.

```
create_api = "http://..."

AuthToken = "bearer ...."

headers = {}
headers["content-type"] = 'multipart/form-data'
headers["Authorization"] = AuthToken

data = {}

data["owner"] = "test"

data["email"] = ""
data["mobile"] = ""
data["badge"] = ""

req = requests.post(create_api,data=data,headers=headers)
```

when i print req.content it is showing the status code 500

i went through so many related questions in stackoverflow. But none of the answers worked for me.

Comment: Post your error here (the response from the server, not the status code). Also, did you try to change the user agent ?

Comment: i didnt change the user agent .do i want to change that ??, but the same code working for some other apis with the content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded without adding any user agent.

Comment: i dont have the access to that server. i am only getting this "some errors occured" with status code 500.

Comment: Different APIs have different User-Agents. You don't need access to the server, read the response that is returned from your request, not your response code. If it is `some errors occurred` like you said, that's fine, nothing more to do about that.

Comment: Ref This Question and Accepted Answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48621130/cannot-upload-files-to-django-rest-framework-using-react-js/48622705#48622705